# Thunderbird Conversations add-on: how to select email account to reply from

Tags: email, add-on, thunderbird

Within the Thunderbird Conversations add-on and when replying to an email, how can i select which of my several email accounts to reply from?  I can't change the default, which seems to be to reply from the email address the message was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that feature is not yet implemented. It is not very hard though so I would be more than happy to integrate the patch for it. Thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple identities, you can edit the identity and check "Reply from this identity". Type your identity address in the input